# Trouble with finding the correct lines of code to determine distribution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Struggling with a few lines of coding.

This is the context:
Consider the experiment where a fair coin is tossed 1000 times and let X be the
number of times that the pattern of three consecutive heads appears. Note that
overlaps are allowed, so that if the sequence is HHHHTT · · · TT, then X = 2.
Estimate
the probability mass function of X and use this to estimate the
mean and variance of X. Report your (moment) estimates.

This is the template provided and highlighted is the 5 lines of code I need to add and their instructions.

```
clear all

N=1000; %Number of Die Rolls
nreps=10000;
count=zeros(1,N+1); %count will be a vector of size N+1 such that, for i=0...N, c(i+1)/nreps=P(X=i)     

for n=1:nreps
     n_3H = 0; %count the number of occurrences of the pattern HHH
        ***%Add code to toss a coin N times***
      for i=3:N
        if  ***%Add condition that the pattern HHH appears at position (i-2,i-1,i)***
            n_3H = n_3H+1;
        end
      end
     ***%Add code to increment count(n_3H+1) by 1***
end

RelFreq = count/nreps;

meanX  ***%Add code to estimate the mean of X***
varX  ***%Add code to estimate the variance of X***
```

So far, this is what I have, but it does not seem to be returning anything and I am unsure of what I should do to continue.

```
clear all

 N=1000; %Number of Die Rolls
nreps=100;
count=zeros(1,N+1);%count will be a vector of size N+1 such that, for i=0...N, c(i+1)/nreps=P(X=i)     

for n=1:nreps
     n_3H = 0; %count the number of occurrences of the pattern HHH
      flipStates = randi([1, 2], 1, N)  %Add code to toss a coin N times
      for i=3:N
        if  strfind(flipStates, [1,1,1])%Add condition that the pattern HHH appears at position (i-2,i-1,i)
            n_3H = n_3H+1;
        end
      end
      %Add code to increment count(n_3H+1) by 1
end

RelFreq = count/nreps;

meanX  %Add code to estimate the mean of X
varX  %Add code to estimate the variance of X
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

because of the looping throughout the entire toss sequence and check for each sub-sequence individually, you should do:

`if  all(flipStates(i-2:i) == [1,1,1])`

what you did is checking `if` condition on a vector which MATLAB translates as `if all(vector)`.

your approach is correct if you take it out (actually instead) of the loop: `for i=3:N ...` and do: `n_3H = numel(strfind(flipStates,[1 1 1]))`

Comment: Do you know what lines of code I would need to use to find the mean and variance of X? And does my n_3H just show the number of times HHH appears for my first repetition or the average of all 100 repetitions? Thank you though, I tried your initial suggestion and n_3H now actually gives a valid answer!

Comment: @PaulDresner Check the functions [`mean`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) and [`var`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html)

Comment: What code would I have to put down so I have multiple answers in my n_3H that would allow me to calculate the mean? @LuisMendo

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want the mean of `X` and `X` is a vector, just use `mean(X)`

Comment: For example right now, I'm running the test 100 times - however, I only get one result in my n_3H file. I was just wondering if you knew how to make it list all the 100 results, of which I could use to get the mean. @LuisMendo